# AngularJS Directive: $scope não atualiza a UI

Tags: angularjs

Bom, estou tentando filtrar os livros de acordo com a area que a pessoa selecionar. Até ai tudo bem, consigo pegar os valores da area e do banco, mas a UI não atualiza a listagem.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="filtros-acervo">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="filtro-titulo">
            <h3>Filtros:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 filtros" ng-repeat="area in areas">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group> {{area.descricao}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular

```
app.controller('Acervo', function($scope,$http){

$scope.livros = []; // Cria um array vazio de livros
$scope.limite = 30; // Define o limite max de livros por pagina
$scope.paginacao = 0; // Paginacao começa do 0
$scope.array = []; // Cria um array vazio (vai servir no selecionar areas)

// Busca todos os livros
$http.get('config/all').success(function(data){
    if (data != 0) {
        $scope.livros = data;
    }
    else {
        $scope.livros = '';
    }
    // Retorna a quantidade de paginas necessarias
    $scope.paginas = function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.livros.length / $scope.limite);
    }
});

// Busca todas as areas
$http.get('areas').success(function(areas){
    $scope.areas = areas;
});
```

})

Directive

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function ($http) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.area.id);
                // Add se marcado
                if (elem[0].checked) {
                    if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.area.id);
                }
                // Remove se desmarcado
                else {
                    if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                }
                $http.post('config/livrosAreas', {"area" : scope.array}).success(function(data){
                    scope.livros = data;
                    // Retorna a quantidade de paginas necessarias
                    scope.paginas = function(){
                        return Math.ceil(scope.livros.length / scope.limite);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

O Banco me da o retorno que quero certinho, só não atualiza a listagem de livros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na sua directive.
Quando o Angular atualiza o escopo a partir da sua chamada em `scope.$apply` o seu ajax ainda não terminou a execução, assim as atualizações só irão aparecer na próxima mudança no escopo.
O correto seria você realizar o ajax antes de atualizar o escopo. Dessa forma sua directive muda para:

```
.directive("checkboxGroup", function ($http) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('click', function () {
                var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.area.id);
                // Add se marcado
                if (elem[0].checked) {
                    if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.area.id);
                }
                // Remove se desmarcado
                else {
                    if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                }
                $http.post('config/livrosAreas', {"area" : scope.array}).success(function(data){
                    scope.livros = data;
                    // Retorna a quantidade de paginas necessarias
                    scope.paginas = function(){
                        return Math.ceil(scope.livros.length / scope.limite);
                    }
                }).then(function(){
                    scope.$apply();
                });
        });
    }
}
```